# Comunicación entre pantalla Nextion (Nextion Editor) y Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino

Recién estoy comenzando a usar Nextion Editor y tengo el siguiente problema. En el Editor Nextion, tengo un botón de ON/OFF. Es verde cuando está ON y rojo cuando está OFF. Quiero que cuando una persona presione este botón en la pantalla (que inicialmente está apagado), antes de cambiar su estado (y por lo tanto su color), envíe este estado al Arduino UNO. Arduino debería reconocer que está encendido y enviar un 'OK' a la pantalla como una forma de decir 'Confirmo que se ha realizado la conexión entre ambos, y te envío un OK para que cambies el estado del botón'. Una vez que se recibe el 'OK' en la pantalla (que no modifica ningún objeto de texto, es solo una señal enviada por Arduino y no debe mostrarse en la pantalla), solo entonces debe cambiar el color y el estado del botón.

Mi código en Arduino es muy simple y no sé cómo modificarlo para lograr lo anterior:

```
char val;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
if(Serial.available()>0){
val = Serial.read();
Serial.print(val);
}
}
```